# Properly copying an array from one function to another

Tags: c, arrays, function, binary, return

my C question is how to properly take the binary array I get in binaryConversion() and copy it to integer.binary, within makeInt().

I tried to make binaryConversion() return a pointer which then would be dereferenced and copied over to the new array, but I am almost certain this is wrong in some way.
This is my failed attempt:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct Integer{
    int decimal;
    int binary[32];
};

int * binaryConversion(int num){
    int bin_buffer[32];
    int * ptr = bin_buffer;
    unsigned int mask = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        if(mask & num == 1){
            bin_buffer[i] = 1;
        }
        else{
            bin_buffer[i] = 0;
        }
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    return ptr;
}

struct Integer makeInt(int num){
    struct Integer integer;
    int * ptr = binaryConversion(num);
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        integer.binary[i] = *(ptr+i);
    }

}
```

and it must work with this driver code:

```
struct Integer makeInt(int);

void binaryTester(int array[], int test[], int size){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        assert(array[i] == test[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){

int size = sizeof(int) * 8;
    int array[size], i;
    struct Integer test;
    printf("\n\t=========Test #7: Conversion of 2===========\n\n");
    test = makeInt(2);
    int test1[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};

    printf("\n\t\t....Converting 2 Passed\n");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For starters, your `binaryConversion` function has undefined behavior.  You must not return the address of a variable allocated on the stack.

Comment: regarding: `unsigned int mask = INT_MIN;` this is trying to convert a negative integer to an unsigned integer.

Comment: in function: `makeInt()`  the local variable `integer` is set but never used.

Comment: regarding: `assert(array[i] == test[i]);`  1) the code is missing the header file: `assert.h`  2) the `assert()` function should not be used in production code, only debug code

Comment: regarding: `struct Integer makeInt(int);`  this would only be necessary if the function: `makeInt()` were being called before it is defined.  Otherwise, this is just cluttering the code and should be removed

Comment: OT:  The scope of local variables should be as limited as reasonably possible.  I.E. This: `int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)` should be: `for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)

Comment: regarding: `int size = sizeof(int) * 8;`  on most modern systems this will result in 32 or 64 depending on the underlying hardware architecture

Comment: the function: `makeInt()` should contain a `return value;` statement because its' signature states that it returns the struct `Integer`  However, the function doesn't actually return anything but trash.

Comment: regarding: `int test1[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};`  this is setting the contents of the array: `test1[]`  However, that array is never used

Comment: the posted code will 'compile' with lots of critical warnings.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gmu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: the posted code fails to ever execute the function: `void binaryTester(int array[], int test[], int size)`

Comment: the function: `binaryConversion()` is returning a pointer to a buffer on the local stack of that function.  That local buffer will 'go out of scope' when that function exits.  I.E. it will no longer be a valid entity.  The result is undefined behavior